# Relationship of two Linear Transform Matrices in two different equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Assume that vector $\alpha \in \Bbb{F}^n$ and matrix $A_{n\times n}$, we define a linear transform $\mathscr{A}: \Bbb{F}^n \rightarrow \Bbb{F}^n$. 
$$\mathscr{A}(\alpha)=A\alpha$$
Now assume that $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_n\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb{F}^n$, we apply $\mathscr{A}$ to the basis.
$$
\begin{align}
\mathscr{A}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_n) & =(\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots,\beta_n)\\
& = (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_n)A'
\end{align}
$$
What's the relationship between $A$ and $A'$, are they the same? If the answer is YES/NO, how can I prove/disprove it.

Comment: I didn't understand what are $\alpha_i$. Are they elements of a basis (i.e. vectors) or basis them self? I think the first but you wrote "set of basis" so I'm confused

Comment: I mean the first. I've edited my problem. Thank you for your comment

Comment: I think the concept you are looking for is the change of basis, but I have difficulties to understand your notation. $\mathscr{A}$ takes vectors, what is the meaning of $\mathscr{A}(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$?

Comment: It's the short form of $(\mathscr{A}(\alpha_1),\mathscr{A}(\alpha_2),\cdots,\mathscr{A}(\alpha_n))$

Comment: Ah, and $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n) A'$ stands for?

Comment: We have each $\beta_i=k_{1i}\alpha_1+k_{2i}\alpha_2+\cdots+k_{ni}\alpha_n$, so $\beta_i=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots ,\alpha_n)\cdot (k_{1i},k_{2i},\cdots, k_{ni})^T$. So the jth column of $A'$ is a vector $(k_{1i},k_{2i},\cdots, k_{ni})^T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the matrix whose columns are the $\alpha_i$ by $P$ and the matrix whose columns are the $\beta_i$ by $B$. You have $AP = B$ and you want to find a matrix $A'$ such that $PA' = B$. Thus,

$$ A' = P^{-1}B = P^{-1}AP. $$

Comment: Do you mean that unless $n=1$, there does not exits an $A'$ satisfy the equation? Actually I mean $\beta_i=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots ,\alpha_n)\cdot (k_{1i},k_{2i},\cdots, k_{ni})^T$ so I have $(\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots ,\beta_n)=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots ,\alpha_n)A'$. Split the equation $\beta_i=\alpha_i A'$ gets only a trivial result of $n=1$.

Comment: Your notation is not clear. By $(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ do you mean a $n \times n$ matrix whose columns are the $\alpha_i$ and by $(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n) A'$ do you mean the multiplication of matrices?

Comment: yes, I exactly mean that.

Comment: I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. It surprised me that the answer is so simple and elegent